# Is device address is virtual address? what is functionality of mmap in this case?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, kernel32

Is device address is virtual address? what is functionality of mmap in this case?or device address mapped to physical address

Answer (score 0):

Usally, device address are allocated by specific system/host bus. It can identify devices on the bus. 
Virtual address and physical address are used in memory system.

For mmap, the system allocate an I/O address for specific device in physical address space, application can access device in the way of memory access.

Answer (score 0):

Usually devices comes with resources like registers, internal memory, etc that can be accessed from the CPU.

In order to be able to access a specific device register for example from the *CPU* you need to know the physical address of this device registers and then map this physical address to either kernel or user depending on your use case.

mmap maps resources to be accessed from user space. The result of mmap is a user space cpu address that is mapped to this resource.

This resource can be anything. It can be:

- a file
- anonymous memory
- some external device resource ( memory, registers, etc )

mmap can't directly map device registers for example simply because it doesn't know how to do that. In this case you will probably need add some kernel space support for your mmap operation.